# SVN W155007 ... is not a working copy - immediately after import and checkout

Tags: svn

I'm trying to follow the doc for SVN.  If I'm reading it correctly, immediately after importing, I must do a checkout and that will create a working copy.  then I should be able to do a "status".

Below is exactly what I did.  Am I understanding wrong, or typed something wrong?

```
c:\Code>svn import c:/Code/Demo file:///c:/SVNRepository -m "Initial Checkin"
Adding  (bin)  Demo\Sample1.ps1
Adding  (bin)  Demo\Sample2.ps1

Committed revision 1.

c:\Code>svn checkout file:///c:/SVNRepository
A    SVNRepository\Sample1.ps1
A    SVNRepository\Sample2.ps1
Checked out revision 1.

c:\Code>svn status
svn: warning: W155007: 'C:\Code' is not a working copy
c:\Code>cd demo

c:\Code\Demo>svn status
svn: warning: W155007: 'C:\Code\Demo' is not a working copy
```

Comment: It's not the forward vs backslash is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `C:\Code\SVNRepository`, that should be your working copy.  According to [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) of the `checkout` command:

> usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
>
> ...
>
> **If PATH is omitted, the basename of the URL will be used as the destination.** If multiple URLs are given each will be checked out into a sub-directory of PATH, with the name of the sub-directory being the basename of the URL.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  Page 18 of PDF does not show specifying a PATH on the checkout, I assumed it was current directory.  I added path, then get "Tree conflict" and had to type "r" for resolve on my two files.  Isn't it normal for the first time checkin that the Import-from directory will be the check-out directory?

Comment: The PATH is optional (indicated by the square brackets) and defaults to the value I quoted above.  If you see conflicts on a checkout, you must have checked out into the same folder you imported.  To avoid those conflicts (i.e. you *know* your local folder matches the folder on the repository), use `--force` in your `checkout` command.  This just versions your files if they're the same.  If they're different, they'll show up as modifications (that you can commit if you'd like).